# how to print the anchor tags in the sub-class using beautiful soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, anchor

I want to print :

- all the anchor tags in the sub-class i.e. "brandChild"  of the class ="brandGroup choose_a"

html:

```
<div id="brandGroup" class="brandGroup choose_a">
   <div class="brandChild"><a href="abc.com">comments</a></div>
   <div class="brandChild"><a href="xyz.com">comments</a></div>
   <div class="brandChild"><a href="fgh.com">comments</a></div>
<div>
```

```
x=soup.find('div', id="brandGroup", class_="brandGroup choose_a").find_all('div',class_="brandChild")
for i in x:
    print(i.find_all('a'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is just 1 `a` in the `brandChild`, you can use `find('a', href=True)` and then use `a['href']` to get the `href` itself:

```py
for i in soup.find('div', id="brandGroup", class_="brandGroup choose_a").find_all('div',class_="brandChild"):

    a = i.find('a', href=True)
    print(a['href'])
```

---

That said, consider using `select()` with a CSS selector, this way you can target your `a` a much more readable way:

```py
for i in soup.select('#brandGroup > .brandChild > a', href=True):
    print(i['href'])
```

---

Both snippets print:

```
abc.com
xyz.com
fgh.com
```